# Chrome not going Headless in selenium python on ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am pretty new to Selenium python on ubuntu. I am trying to run chrome headless,But my it won't go headless.
here is the snippet of my code.

chrome version : 80.0.3987.132

```
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Chrome is working as-usual(with head) without giving any exceptions.

Comment: I think you need "--disable-gpu" flag.... but why maximize a window that doesn't exist?

Comment: I tried "--disable-gpu" option,still not working. Maximising the window just in case i don't need to use scroll in future.Thanks for help

Comment: include any exceptions you receive in your post.  You may also want to mention if the browser launches at all.  I think you need the full path to the driver there, btw... but if the browser is launching that's not the issue.

Comment: No Exceptions,code is running fine but only problem is window is opening.(not going headless)

Comment: Try with "options=options"